# Select-Xml returns file name

Tags: powershell, select-xml

When parsing my *.csproj using Select-Xml, besides from the expected output i also get a concat of a parameter.

What is going on here?

```
$version = Select-Xml -Path $projectFilePath -XPath "/Project/PropertyGroup/Version"
Write-Host $version
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
EXIT
```

this returns

> 1.0.1:D:\somepath\someproject.csproj

instead of

> 1.0.1

snippet of csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.3</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the snippet so now I could try myself.

This does work:

```
$version = Get-Content -Path $projectFilePath -Raw | Select-Xml -XPath "/Project/PropertyGroup/Version"
Write-Host $version
```

Comment: still a bit surprised why the original code results in that but ok... at least this works

Comment: @Dbl Indeed. Seems like a bug to me. Also using `LiteralPath` appends the filename to the wanted result of the Xpath query..

Answer (score 2):

you could do this as well:

```
[xml]$x = get-content D:\somepath\someproject.csproj 
$x.project.propertygroup.version
```